# binance python api: sell entire balance function for any asset

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance

I want a python function to sell the entire balance of an asset to USDT.
If I have n ETH, this function should transfer the entire ETH balance to USDT.

I tried something like:

```
bal = client.get_asset_balance(asset='ETH')['free']
sell = client.order_market_buy(symbol='ETHUSDT', quantity = bal)
print(sell)
```

This sometimes outputs a Api Error: Insufficient Balance
for some reason.
Please help me with a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use buy order.
Use "client.order_market_sell" instead of "client.order_market_buy"